# Why can't I find a slash in indexOf with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
mystring = "playlist/323";
if(mystring.indexOf('playlist/') == 1) {
    alert("We got it");
} else {
    alert("We don't");
}
```

I expect it to be show "we got it", but it doesn't.

See my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P2TcW/

Comment: String indices are 0-based. Change your `1` to a `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index of the `/` should not return 1 in your case. If it does not exist in your string, `indexOf` will return `-1`.

```
if(mystring.indexOf('playlist/') > -1) {
    alert("We got it");
} else {
    alert("We don't");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Indexes are zero-based in javascript, your if statement should look like this:

```
if(mystring.indexOf('playlist/') == 0)
```

Comment: It'll only be `0` when the string **starts** with "playlist/".

Comment: @Pointy Valid point, I assumed the OP was after this behaviour though as they said "I expect it to show" =]

Answer (score 1):

Because the first character in the string is at index 0, not 1.

The solution is:

```
if(mystring.indexOf('playlist/') === 0)
```

(Use the strict equality operator, it is good practice as it tests both type and value rather than just value).

Answer (score 1):

indexOf will not equal 1 because the index of the string "playlist/" is really 0, it starts at 0, if you get anything back other than -1, you have a match

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

I think there is a slight misunderstanding in the way you interpret **indexOf**.

`alert(mystring.indexOf('/')); //gives you 8`

```
alert(mystring.indexOf('l')); //gives you 1
```

`alert(mystring.indexOf('playlist/')); //gives you 0`

```
if(mystring.indexOf('playlist/') == 0){ //correct way
alert("we got it");
}
```